# Update variable when clicking button

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I have a slideshow displaying some images. There is a function to make the current image displayed fullscreen when clicking it:

```
var img = document.querySelectorAll(".main-webcam-img")[slideIndex-1];

img.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = img.src;
}
```

I have `prev`, `next` buttons to scroll through the images:

```
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
```

and a function to see what the current slide is:

```
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
```

**The problem:** When clicking the buttons `slideIndex`changes (as it should), but `var img = document.querySelectorAll(".main-webcam-img")[slideIndex-1];` doesn`t update.

Comment: You are never calling your query again, so it will always remain the same. Include the query in the `showSlides` function, or run the query once, but keep it as a NodeList and only access it by index within the `showSlides` function.

Comment: Moved the `img variable` and got it to work. Thank you :)